# Irrational numbers proof by contradiction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

$$\sqrt{2}=a/b$$

$$2=\frac {a^2}{b^2}$$

$$b^2=2a^2$$

since $2a^2$ is even $b^2$ is even, so is $b$

let $b=2c$  we have $4c^2=2a^2$ and thus $a^2=2c^2$ since $2c^2$ is even and since $a^2$ is, even so, is $a$

so $ \sqrt{2}$ is irrational right.

Now HERE THE QUESTION?

same steps for $\sqrt{4}$

$$\sqrt {4}=a/b$$

$$4=\frac {a^2}{b^2}$$

$$4b=2a^2$$

since $4a^2$ is even $b^2$ is even, so is $b$

let $b=4c$ we have $16c^2=2a^2$ and thus $a^2=8c^2$ since $8c^2$ is even and since $a^2$ is, even so, is $a$

but we know $\sqrt {4}$ is a rational number. So?

how does Proof by contradiction suppose to prove the truth!

Also when an even number is multiplied by a number it will be even.

EDIT: the question is if I use the same steps for $\sqrt2$ for $\sqrt 4$ it doesn't work, am I doing it wrong? or...

EDIT 2: I read this thanks to one of the comments [Prove the sqrt of 4 is irrational, where did I go wrong?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2270591/prove-the-sqrt-of-4-is-irrational-where-did-i-go-wrong) can someone dumb down the answer so I can understand, what's going on

Comment: please don't put my question on hold as I need an answer. I need to understand

Comment: How about you link to which answer you don't understand first? Also, here is how to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Have you looked through [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2270591/prove-the-sqrt-of-4-is-irrational-where-did-i-go-wrong)? There is already a good answer there, and if you still do not get something, you can ask a separate question about what exactly you do not understand.

Comment: You missed one step : we have to assume that $\dfrac a b$ have no common divisor.

Comment: When you apply it to $4 = \dfrac {a^2}{b^2}$ we get $4b^2=a^2$ and this is consistent with $a=2b$.

Comment: It's hard for us to "dumb down" the answer specifically so you can understand what's going on, because we don't know know what you understand and what you don't understand. That's why it's important to read the answer, as best you can, and highlight the parts you don't understand. The more information about what about the answer is causing confusion, the better placed we are to help you.

Comment: Repost of this [deleted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3240047/42969)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion, stems from not keeping variables straight. In the first proof, you actually hit:$$2b^2=a^2$$ which implies a is even, first. This, by substitution, and simplification, gives back:$$b^2=2c^2$$ implying b is also even. These combine, to contradict ${a\over b}$ ever being in lowest form.

For the second proof, you were supposed to get: $$4b^2=a^2$$ implying a is even. This then follows to: $$4b^2=4c^2$$ This goes to:$$b^2=c^2$$ which taking both sides principle(positive) root, gives:$$b=c$$ which then proves:$$a=2b$$ and leads to:$${2b\over b}=2$$ being our root.

Answer (score 0):

The poduct of two not-divisible-by-two (aka. odd) numbers is odd.

*Proof:* If $n,m$ are odd, we can write $n=2k+1$, $m=2l+1$. Then $nm=4kl+2k+2l+1=2\cdot(2kl+k+l)+1$ is also odd. $\square$

However, the product of two not-divisible-by-four numbers may happen to be divisible by four.

Comment: what happened to your account?

Answer (score 0):

The correct inference is that $b$ is of the form $2c$, since that will still square to a multiple of $4$. More generally, if $p^k|n^2$ with $p$ prime then $p^{\lceil k/2\rceil}|n$. You now have $4a^2=b^2=(2c)^2=4c^2$, giving $a=c$. So, there is no infinite regress.

Answer (score 0):

Your step
$$4b=2a^2$$
is double nonsense. It should be
$$4b^2=a^2$$
Therefore $a$ is even; but we can’t deduce that $b$ is also even.