# false proof of $\root \of 4$ is irrational.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, irrational-numbers, fake-proofs

There is a proof in my math textbook about the fact that $\root \of 2$ is irrational.

**Proof**:

Lets assume that $\root \of 2$ is rational.Then there will exist $2$ coprime natural numbers $p$ , $q > 1$ such that ,
$$ \root \of 2 = \frac{p}{q} \to 2 = \frac{p^2}{q^2} \to 2q = \frac{p^2}{q}$$

Obviously , $2q$ is an integer but $\frac{p^2}{q}$ is not a integer , because $p$ and $q$ are natural numbers , coprime and $q > 1$. So,

$$2q \neq \frac{p^2}{q} \to \root \of 2 \neq \frac{p}{q}$$

So , $\root \of 2$ is an irrational number.$\square$

> But the confusion to me is , it seems like I can use this argument to show that $\root \of 4$ is an irrational number.

**Proof**:

Lets assume that $\root \of 4$ is rational.Then there will exist $2$ coprime natural numbers $p$ , $q > 1$ such that ,
$$ \root \of 4 = \frac{p}{q} \to 4 = \frac{p^2}{q^2} \to 4q = \frac{p^2}{q}$$

Obviously , $4q$ is an integer but $\frac{p^2}{q}$ is not a integer , because $p$ and $q$ are natural numbers , coprime and $q > 1$. So,

$$4q \neq \frac{p^2}{q} \to \root \of 4 \neq \frac{p}{q}$$

So , $\root \of 4$ is an irrational number.$\square$

> Can someone tell me what is wrong with this proof?

Comment: $q$ could be $1$

Comment: If $p=2, q=1$ then $4q = \frac{p^2}{q}$ and $\root \of 4 = \frac{p}{q}$

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2270591/42969

Comment: @MartinR I would not say it is a duplicate , because the proof is kind of different than your linked post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove the sqrt of 4 is irrational, where did I go wrong?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2270591/prove-the-sqrt-of-4-is-irrational-where-did-i-go-wrong)

Comment: @vitamind It is not the same proof.

Comment: As others have already pointed out, with the $q>1$ condition, your proof essentially says $\sqrt{n} \not\in (\mathbb{Q}\setminus\mathbb{Z})$ for all $n$, which is technically correct, but not very useful, since it fails to address the possibility that $\sqrt{n}$ could be an integer, which is of course true when $n$ is a perfect square.

Comment: To answer your question more directly, in both cases, you're saying "$x$ is rational $\implies$ there will exist 2 coprime natural numbers $p,q > 1$ such that $x=\frac{p}{q}$". This is wrong. To make it a valid statement, you need to either give up on coprimality, or to accept $q=1$ as possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You begin your proof saying that $\sqrt4=\frac pq$ with $p$ and $q$ natural coprimes greater than $1$. That works in the case of $\sqrt2$, since $\sqrt2$ is not a natural number, and then, yes, if it could be written as $\frac pq$ with $p$ and $q$ natural coprime numbers, then both of them would have to be greater than $1$. But $\sqrt4$ *is* a natural number. And the assumption that $\sqrt4$ can be written as $\frac pq$ with $p$ and $q$ coprime and $p,q>1$ is false.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos how does one prove that $\root \of 4$ is a natural number but $\root \of 2$ is not.

Comment: You have $1^2=1<2$ and, if $n$ is a natural number greater than $1$, then $n\geqslant2$, and therefore $n^2\geqslant4$. So, there is no $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $n^2=2$. And $\sqrt4=2\in\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be trying to understand the [Proof by contradiction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction) method used for the irrationality of numbers.

---

You can do the right steps as follows:

Let $\gcd(m,n)=1$, then you have

$$\sqrt 4=\frac mn$$

$$4=\frac {m^2}{n^2}$$

$$m^2=4n^2$$

This implies, $m=2k$. Hence,

$$4k^2=4n^2$$

$$k=n$$

This means, $$m=2k=2n$$

Finally,

$$\sqrt 4=\frac mn=\frac{2n}{n}=2.$$

---

#### Proof - verification

> Lets assume that $\root \of 4$ is rational.Then there will exist $2$ coprime natural numbers $p$ , $q > 1$ such that ,
> $$ \root \of 4 = \frac{p}{q} \to 4 = \frac{p^2}{q^2} \to 4q = \frac{p^2}{q}$$
>
> Obviously , $4q$ is an integer but $\frac{p^2}{q}$ is not a integer , because $p$ and $q$ are natural numbers , coprime and $q > 1$.

Your error strarts here:

You claim that $p,q> 1$. This claim is wrong.  The correct claim should be as follows:

$$\gcd(p,q)=1.$$

> Obviously , $4q$ is an integer but $\frac{p^2}{q}$ is not a integer.

This claim is also wrong. Because, $q=1$ is a counter-example.

Comment: @MorganRodgers It seems the OP has now added something to the answer

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Thank you for your reviewing.

Answer (score 4):

If $p,\,q$ are coprime natural numbers, $q|p^2$ iff $q=1$. The condition $p/q=\sqrt{2}$ contradicts $q=1$ because $\sqrt{2}$ isn't an integer, but $p/q=\sqrt{4}$ doesn't because $\sqrt{4}$ is. So while $q>1$ finishes the first proof, it can't be deduced in the second. In particular, we need only check $1^2<2<2^2=4$ to see $\sqrt{4}$, but not $\sqrt{2}$, is natural.

Answer (score 3):

The restriction that $p,q$ should be $>1$ is unwarranted in either proofs, unnecessary in the first one and false for the second one. It should have been stated for what it was: that $p,q\in\Bbb Z$ coprime numbers such that $q\ge1$. Then the proof for $\sqrt 2$ goes more or less $$[2q^2=p^2]\Rightarrow [2\mid p]\Rightarrow [q^2=2\left(p/2\right)^2]\Rightarrow [2\mid q]$$

But then $2\mid\operatorname{gcd}(p,q)=1$.

Your second attempt at a proof relies on a false theorem, therefore the rest is hardly worth worrying about.